# Navbar dropdown menu href links not a working properly (Django+Bootstrap)

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I am creating a small web application with using Django and Bootstrap4. In my Project Folder in Django, I have the templates and one of them is the base template. The other templates extend the base template. I have added the Bootstrap CDN to the base template and is working fine. I have created Bootstrap Navbar which get a dropdown when adjusted to screen size.

The issue is when I click a nav-link it adds the path in its href to the current path displayed in my browser i.e the location of the previous nav-link and searches for that. Hence it gives me an error. Upon clicking it should only take the path of only the clicked nav-link. My code is below. The href links are coming from my urls.py file. Please advise how to resolve this. Thanks.

[base.html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmz0O.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add your code to your question as a text and not a screenshot, see also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Django. The problem is you are using relative urls, instead of absolute, or root-relative urls. Here are examples of all three:

- `some-page/`

  - This is a relative url. It will take you to whatever page you're on plus "some-page/"
- `https://example.com/some-page/`

  - This is an absolute url. It will take you to the exact url no matter where you are on the site.
- `/some-page/`

  - This is a root-relative url. It will take you to your root domain (`https://example.com` in this case), plus the url given. This is the preferred option, because you don't have to change it from development (it will take you to `127.0.0.1:8000/some-page/`) to production.

Now, since you're using Django, you can do something even better: use Django's built-in `url` templatetag. You would modify your href to be something like this, using the `name` of each path given in your `urls.py` file:

```html
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
<!-- OR <a href="{% url 'profiles:login' %}">Login</a> if the url is in your profiles/urls.py file -->
```

Doing it this way is best, because if later you want to change the exact url (say, to 'profile/log-in/'), you only need to do so in your `urls.py` file, and not in any HTML files you have the old url defined.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your prompt response. I followed your suggestion. It now gives an error " Invalid block tag on line 16: ''profile:login''. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"   My Urls.py has the following:  path('profile/login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name = 'profile:login'),
    path('profile/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name = 'profile:logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name = 'register'),

Comment: Double-check that you're using the url tag correctly in your html file. Looks like you have an error there.

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py, add a name to your each URL.

```
     path('profile/login', views.login, name='login')
```

In template add this as href:

```
href="{% url 'login' %}"
```

Comment: `href='{% url 'login' %}'` shoud be `href="{% url 'login' %}"` or `href='{% url "login" %}'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. It works now. I used the href="{% url 'login' %} and ensured that the name-tag matched my urls.py file entry.